# Set default value for a dynamic route/ page in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, routes, nuxt.js

When someone is referred to my site I want the URL to look something like this

`localhost:3000/<dynamic affiliate username>/home`

But when someone is not referred to my site and is a guest I would like the URL to default to something like this

`localhost:3000/www/home`

Is there a way for me to set a default value for a dynamic route/ page using Nuxt.js?

Answer (score 0):

Use [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware)

#### 1. Page middleware

You can check the user in middleware (by cookie or something else you use. In this example I used nuxt [auth module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/))

Named middleware

```js
/* pages/_user/home.vue */
export default {
  middleware: "auth"
}
```

Anonymous

```js
/* pages/_user/home.vue */
export default {
  middleware({ $auth, redirect }) {
    if(!$auth.loggedIn) {
      redirect("/www/home")
    }
  }
}
```

#### 2. Router middleware

If you want to apply this logic globally in the project (on each child route of `_user` page for example), you can set router middleware in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
/* nuxt.config.js */
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"] // or "auth" for single middleware 
  }
}
```

```js
/* middleware/auth.js */
export default ({ $auth, route, redirect }) => {
  if(funcToDetectUserPage(route.path)) {
    if(!$auth.loggedIn) {
      redirect("/www/home");
    }
  }
}
```